# Как менять keywords, и title, при использовании AJAX?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

К примеру во такой кусок кода:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a').click(function() {
            var url = $(this).attr('href');

            $.ajax({
                url:     url + '?ajax=1',
                success: function(data){
                    $('#content').html(data);
                }
            });

            if(url != window.location){
                window.history.pushState(null, null, url);
            }

            return false;
        });

        $(window).bind('popstate', function() {
            $.ajax({
                url:     location.pathname + '?ajax=1',
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#content').html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Он подгружает контент в div content. Это все хорошо, но как менять область head? Keywords, title, и т.д...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поменять можно легко. Например, при загрузке страницы, на `native JS`:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
     document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].querySelector('title').innerHTML = 'test';

     //или даже так для title
     //document.title = 'test';
});
```

При загрузке страницы, на `jQuery` можно так:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('title').html('тест');
});
```

Соответственно, `title` можно заменить на любой нужный Вам тэг. Собственно поменять значение тегов можно в любой момент, не только при загрузке.

Comment: Да это я знаю, все варианты представлены здесь меняют title, как быть с ajax + History API? Title поменяется только если обновить страницу...

Comment: @ВадимПедченко, добавить строку с изменением title в событие `popstate`

Comment: @ВадимПедченко, [вот так вот](http://jsfiddle.net/0u9hw6w7/) у меня заработало.

Comment: То же самое((((

Comment: @ВадимПедченко, когда назад нажимаете не работает же? [Вот так вот тогда](http://jsfiddle.net/0u9hw6w7/1/). Я так логику всю сломал, да?

Comment: Да нет, работает...